# Installing an app (.apk file) from the native Android HTMLViewer 8.1

Tags: installation, browser, apk, html

I have a tablet that's locked up pretty good (Android 8.1). Locked bootloader, managed android OS, proprietary apps, etc... I'm trying to see if I can get an app to install on it. One way I've thought of is through the Android HTMLViewer (version 8.1).

The tablet has a help file that's HTML, which opens with HTMLViewer. So I tried throwing an apk file in the same directory, and seeing if I could modify the help.html file with an anchor tag that points to the apk.

I've tried the following:

```
<a href="test.apk">download</a>

<a href="test.apk" download>download</a>

<a href="test.apk" type="application/vnd.android.package-archive">download</a>

<a href="test.apk" type="application/vnd.android.package-archive" download>download</a>
```

Each one gives that same result. The viewer simply tries to parse the file and gives me a huge jumble of whacky characters.

I thought about writing a small script in Javascript utilizing the `FileReader` object, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript).

However, I'm quite certain that HTML viewer is so slimmed down, it probably doesn't support this object. It is compatible with jquery, so I suppose there is some hope for this.

Any ideas on how I could tweak this to accomplish my goal would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your main problem is not the download but how you start the package manager which is responsible for app installation. But based on your description it is not clear how the device is locked. What have you tried so far and why does each method fails?

Comment: @Robert This device built for a secure environment... So it's super tight. No adb, slimmed down settings, fileObserver that deletes files that aren't supposed to be there. In short, it's one helluva challenge. It's a customized ROM. There was one exploit that worked, and has since been patched. So I'm looking for other potential.